# Replace "And" with "and" in mysql using replace query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query in mysql:

```
update TABLENAME set columnname = replace(columnname, 'And', 'and');
```

the purpose was to replace And with and ("A" should be lowercase). The problem is it cannot find the "And" in database, but if I use like "%And%" then it can find it along with many other ands that are part of a word or even the ones that are already lowercase.

Comment: Define 'cannot find the "And" in the database'. What happens instead? Nothing? Wrong result? Computer explodes?

Comment: Why not just use LOWER()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only want to replace whole words of 'And' they will all have leading and trailing spaces (unless someone has some bad punctuation such as 'and,'). So include those spaces in the search - ie

```
update TABLENAME set columnname = replace(columnname, ' And ', ' and ');
```

SQL Fiddle showing your result. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3f8fa/1

Comment: Where does he say anything about whole words?

Comment: @EJP here - " along with many other ands that are part of a word"

Comment: Exactly. Part of a word. These are column names.

Comment: @EJP Sorry , but I respectfully ask if you've read the question properly. OP is looking to replace instances of 'And' with 'and' within columns, that obviously contain other information as well. It is only the whole words he wants replaced, not names such as Andrew.

Comment: Thank you very much Simo, the problem was the space as well as something in the php code that capitalized the title, I was able to put exception for And and this fixe the issue along with your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

The *replace* function is case **sensitive**. Thus

```
update TABLENAME set columnname = replace(columnname, 'And', 'and');
```

may update no row if no columnname has exactly 'And' in it.

`LIKE`, instead, is case **insensitive**, thus

```
SELECT columnname FROM tablename WHERE columnname LIKE '%And%';
```

may return results, having 'And', 'and', 'AND', ... in columnname.

Comment: replace() function searches for the "substring" - so don't use the wildcard.  If OP was doing a search, use LIKE '%And%', but not with the replace() function.

Comment: He doesn't need to change 'and' to 'and', and the only change be actually mentions wanting is 'A' to 'a'.

Comment: @EJP The OP says the *replace* func doesn't seem to find/replace 'And's - he says also the `LIKE '%And%'` returns rows. The answer tries to provide an explanation: basically there could be no 'And', only 'and' ; but since LIKE is case insensitive, some rows are shown.

Comment: @simo.3792095 Where do you see wildcards in the *replace* usage from my answer? See also my comment above.

Comment: @ring0, yeah I was reading your post again anyway, And I probably miss understood that you were explaining the behaviour that the OP was seeing.  Somehow I read into it that you were suggesting he insert the wild card, in order to get more results. My bad.

Comment: @ring0 you should include a space in between the % wildcard to get a correct result.. that way its finding the word and :)